# Loop through stackPanel.children genericaly

Tags: casting, combobox, foreach, controls, stackpanel

In code I am dynamically adding controls (e.g. TextBox, ComboBox, Label, etc) that I would like to now loop through and get the values from each applicable (e.g. not Labels) control that a user inputted data for.

```
        foreach (Control control in EditForm.Children)
        {
            values = new List<string>();
            fieldName = control.Name;

            if (control is ComboBox)
            {
                ComboBox cmb = control as ComboBox;

                string value = cmb.SelectedValue.ToString();
            }
         }
```

The problem is that I get an error during runtime of

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' to
>   type 'System.Windows.Controls.Control'.

Is there a more generic class I should be using instead of 'Control'? How can I loop through each control and have access to the needed values (includes the control's Name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"UIElement" is most likely a safe choice.

If you're only interested elements of a specific type, you can also consider using Linq to filter out elements by class type (don't forget to include a "using System.Linq" directive):

```
foreach (ComboBox combo in EditForm.Children.OfType<ComboBox>())
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: The UIElement worked just fine, except for one small thing: UIElement does not have a field called "Name", which is fine, cause all I need to do is move that line to after I cast the variable to the proper control type. Also according to the msdn ComboBox does not inherit from UIElement. Thoughts on the matter?

Comment: It most definitely inherits UIElement (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox(v=vs.85).aspx). Are you perhaps looking at the entry for a WinForm ComboBox?

Comment: You're right. I must've been looking at the wrong one. Thanks for the clarification.