# Where did my Control Label Property go? Unable to access a control property in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, wpf, reporting-services

I'm building out an application to query SQL Server Report Server, return a list of controls for the user to select from, then initiate the report and save the result to a folder of the users choosing.

I began the journey by replicating parts of Ch.15 of Paul Turley's "SQL Server 2016 Reporting Services and Mobile Reports" which gives some basic code examples that extract a simple report to a folder location.  This launching point was intended for very basic reports with a single parameter.  My organization has nearly a thousand reports of various complexity that this application will have to work with.  I have a method:

```
private REService.ParameterValue[] GetReportExecutionParameters()
```

where REService is the Web Reference to ReportExecution2005.asmx.

I build a List of controls:

```
var controlList = new List<Control>();
```

and for each control in my Wpf Stackpanel, I add to the list according to the control type:

```
foreach (var control in StackPanelParameters.Children.OfType<Object>())
```

with a series of if statements:

```
    if (control is DatePicker )
    {
        DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)control;
        controlList.Add(dp);
        continue;
    }
```

then, within the same method, I create a List of values:

```
var parameterValues = new List<REService.ParameterValue>();
```

and attempt to populate the parameterValues with another foreach/if block.

the method in it's entirety.

```
    private REService.ParameterValue[] GetReportExecutionParameters()
    {
        var controlList = new List<Control>();


        //same issue using UIElement....  
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688136/loop-through-stackpanel-children-genericaly
        //***This one helped: 
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298431/traversing-elements-of-stackpanel/22298680#22298680


        //create a list<> of controls extracted from the StackPanel, add them to the "controlList"
        foreach (var control in StackPanelParameters.Children.OfType<Object>())
        {
            if (control is DatePicker )
        {
            DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)control;
            controlList.Add(dp);
            continue;
        }
        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox t = (TextBox)control;
            controlList.Add(t);
            continue;
        }
        if (control is CheckBox)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)control;
            controlList.Add(cb);
            continue;
        }
        if (control is ComboBox)
        {
            ComboBox cbx = (ComboBox)control;
            controlList.Add(cbx);
            continue;
        }
        if (control is Label)
        {
            Label l = (Label)control;
            controlList.Add(l);
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            //the generic case
            Control x = (Control)control;
            controlList.Add(x);
            continue;
        }

    }  //Ok, now I have a populated controlList

    // now I'm assigning the control value to the report parameter
    // per "https://odetocode.com/articles/123.aspx" a different approach?

    var parameterValues = new List<REService.ParameterValue>();

    foreach(var control in controlList)
    {
        if (control is DatePicker)
        {
            parameterValues.Add(new REService.ParameterValue
            { 
                Name = control.Name,
                Value = ((DatePicker)control).ToString()
            });
            continue;
        }
        else if (control is TextBox)
        {
            parameterValues.Add(new REService.ParameterValue
            {
                Name = control.Name,
                Value = ((TextBox)control).Text
            });
            continue;
        }
        else if (control is CheckBox)
        {
            parameterValues.Add(new REService.ParameterValue
            {
                Name = control.Name,
                Value = ((CheckBox)control).IsChecked.ToString()
            });
            continue;
        }
        else if (control is ComboBox)
        {
            parameterValues.Add(new REService.ParameterValue
            {
                Name = control.Name,
                Value = ((ComboBox)control).SelectedItem.ToString()
            });
            continue;
        }
        else if (control is Label)
        {
            parameterValues.Add(new REService.ParameterValue
            {
                //Name = control.ToString(),   
                //Name = control.Name, //this one is null
                //Name = ((System.Windows.Forms.Label)control).label


                //the control doesn't have a Label property, where did I lose you, little Label?
                Name = "",
                Value = ((Label)control).Content.ToString()
            });
            continue;
        }
    }
    return parameterValues.ToArray();
}
```

The error message is generated at the point of generating the report using the collected information from both the user input to the dynamically generated control parameters and the report definition returned from ReportServer using ReportService2010.asmx and ReportExecution2005.asmx.

I get an error, the expectation is for the Name property in the ParameterValue to be populated and I believe the Label value is what it's looking for.  While the Label property exists at he control array level, when I "foreach" it, the Label property is no longer available.

Error:
Message "The required field Name is missing from the input structure. --->

I can't access a CDN to host the screen shots (at work) I have but the **Locals** shows the columns: Name, Value, Type.  When I look at the 'control' variable in the (var control in controlList) under 'Value', I see {System.Windows.Controls.Label: ProcessDate}

When I expand it to look for the Label property, it's not there.  I need the Label and its value.

I get that my problem is a fundamental misunderstanding of how C# works... please instruct me on the error of my ways.

Comment: The error message _"The required field Name is missing from the input structur"_ could be interpreted like you are not allowed to assign an empty `string` to the `ParameterValue.Name` property (when reading the `Label.Content`). You can try to assign it a value and see if this solves the problem.

Comment: You can significantly shorten your code. When generating the `controlList` collection, you don't need to check the individual types of the child elements. You already provided a general collector that collects all `Control` objects. All elements you are inspecting are actually of type `Control`. So all the if-statements are redundant (except the one that filters all `Control` elements). Since you are using a direct cast to cast the child element to `Control`, your code will throw an exception when the element is a not a `Control` (e.g. a `Panel` like a `Grid` or `StackPanel`).

Comment: I am having trouble understanding how you plan to use a label to compute a name+value pair to serve as a report parameter. What is the name and what is the value? Usually a label is paired with another control.